# Aliasing on meshes that overlap grease pencil

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, grease-pencil, antialiasing

[image: example image]

(Blender ver 3.5.1) There's a white contrast outline around meshes in front of grease pencil objects. Grease pencil overlaps OKAY with grease pencil, and mesh overlaps OKAY with mesh, but mesh + grease pencil causes issue. Both in viewport and final render. Any way to have this not render?

Increasing the Anti-Aliasing threshold to 2.0 under Render Properties/Grease Pencil doesn't fix it.